# Highcharts original background color always gets exported

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart with a series of area plots and a line plot with the chart also having an initial background color. The chart has a way to toggle the area and background colors on and off by clicking in the legend (see working jsfiddle). Everything works fine, except for when you turn off the area/background color and try to export the chart. The export always shows the original background color.

http://jsfiddle.net/lamarant/BHkmw/

The code that changes the background color looks like this:

```
if (doHide) {
    this.chart.plotBackground.attr({
        fill: '#fff'
    });
} else {
    this.chart.plotBackground.attr({
        fill: '#000'
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is related with fact, that during export, chart is generated again, so not include dynamic options (like attr()). So you can set global variable, which will keep "current" background, and in exporting options ([chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load)) use load event, which will set correct background.

```
exporting: {
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        load: function () {
                            this.plotBackground.attr({
                                fill: globalBackground
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BHkmw/9/